# How To Implement the Driver Pattern Using Helpers in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, driver, lumen

How would I go about implementing a driver pattern in Lumen? Right now I have a helper `ResponseHandler.php` in `/app/Helpers` which defines an `abstract class ResponseHandler`.

```
// app/Helpers/ResponseHandler.php

namespace App\Helpers;

use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response as HTTPResponse;

abstract class ResponseHandler extends HTTPResponse
{   

    abstract public function success();
    abstract public function fail();
    [...]
}
```

I have drivers defined that `extend ResponseHandler` in the subdirectory `/app/Helpers/Response`. A driver is defined as follows:

```
// app/Helpers/Response/JSON.php

namespace App\Helpers\ResponseHandler;

class JSON extends ResponseHandler
{
    public function fail() {
        // logic
    }

    public function success() {
        // logic
    }

    [...]
}
```

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to use the driver inside a function in my controller, Lumen throws the following error: `Class 'App\Helpers\ResponseHandler\JSON' not found`. This is the controller I've written (irrelevant parts removed):

```
// app/Http/Controllers/ResponseController.php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Helpers\ResponseHandler\JSON as Response;

class ResponseController extends Controller
{
    public function returnSomething($content) {
        [...]
        return Response::success($_ProcessedContent);
    }

    [...]
}
```

I've tried changing namespaces around which just ends up causing more errors and doesn't end up solving this one. I suspect that I'm just not familiar enough with namespaces and how Lumen uses them...but I've been working on this problem for a few hours now and can't seem to figure it out.

Could someone with more experience with Lumen/Laravel shed some light onto this issue for me?

*** [SOLUTION] ***
The design pattern was correct, but I needed to run:

`composer dump-autoload`

after everything was written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running: composer dumpautoload from the command line?

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Though, the command is `composer dump-autoload`, with a dash. Looks like I have some more reading to do on how composer works. Thank you!

For reference: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload